# Compare Previous and Current Values in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with below input and need SQL command to get the output with flag value added internally in query

Table A

Input:

```
Col1  Col2   Col3    
123   20      100    
123   20      101 
121   10      105
121   11      105
120   25      110
120   25      111
124   21      101    
124   21      102       
123   10      100    
123   10      101    
124   11      101    
124   11      102    
125   30      103
125   12      103
```

Expected Output:

```
Col1   Col2  Col3   Flag    
120    25    110     N
120    25    111     N
121    10    105     N
121    20    100     N    
123    20     101    Y    
123    10     100    Y    
123    10     101    Y    
124    21    101     Y        
124    21    102    Y    
124    11     101    Y    
124    11     102    Y    
125    30     103    N    
125    12     103    N
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Please explain the logic used for the tag.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How are you determining current and previous values, as we do not see a unique key in your table.   Are you using an incremental key or a datetime field that is not included above?

Comment: On what basis you wanna add that flag?

Answer (score 0):

use case when . as i have not found any logic of flag so i guess col3>102 will N and rest is Y

```
 select Col1,
Col2,Col3,
case when Col3>102 then 'N' else 'Y' end as flag from yortable
```

Comment: Sorry I missed to explain the logic. If both col1 and col2 previous and current values are same and previous,current values are not same then flag it as Y. If not N

Comment: your dbms please

Comment: @Chakkara your database name please 124    21    101    &        
124    21 flaged Y but 120    25      
120    25 flaged by N whats the logic